# Integer matrix invariant factors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-theory

Have question about finding invariant factors of integer matrix:
$\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 2 \\
-2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}$

Was sick during lectures, and not completely that what I do is right.

What I do:

Well, first lets make

$x\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
6 & 2 \\
-2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x-6 & 2 \\
-2 & x-6
\end{pmatrix}$
such matrix,and discover its determinant, like this:
$det\begin{pmatrix}
x-6 & 2 \\
-2 & x-6
\end{pmatrix}=(x-6)^2+4=x^2-12x+40$

So far so good, but after this.. I am not sure if it is what is asked for:

$x_1=6+2i$ and $x_2=6-2i$, thus $x^2-12x+40=(x-6+2i)(x-6-2i)$

Are $(x-6+2i)$ and $(x-6-2i)$ invariant factors of above mentioned integer matrix? (Basing my thoughts on http://www.math.uh.edu/~klaus/08spt03_solu.pdf , and very well might be way-way off, please dont get too upset)

Comment: You solved the eigenvalues. The invariant factors come from finding [the Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).

Comment: The question of putting a matrix in a normal form, is essentially akin to factorization of numbers into their primes parts, or into a bunch of blocks organized in such a way that each block is associated with a factor of the characteristic polynomial. The fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian group is a good start. The smith normal form captures this.

Comment: Got it. Will delete or answer own question tomorrow. 2 and 20 are invariants